Why auto variant isn't working compared to (equivalent?) template version of function?
I'm working on a C++ project where I want to dispatch events to different modules. I have a base Event class and several derived event types (EventA, EventB, EventC). My modules inherit from a templated Module base class, which uses concepts and SFINAE to dispatch events to the handler in the derived class if it is defined.
It works properly with templates, but not when trying to implement it by using auto keyword only.
Here is a working version with whole context:
struct Event {};
struct EventA : Event {};
struct EventB : Event {};
struct EventC : Event {};

class MyModule;

template <typename T>
concept IsEventType = std::is_base_of_v<Event, T>;

template <typename Dispatcher, typename Dispatchable>
concept CanDispatch = requires(Dispatcher* d, const Dispatchable& e)
{
    { d->dispatch(e) };
};


template <typename Derived>
class Module
{
public:

    void onEvent(const IsEventType auto& e)
    {
        dispatchEvent(e, static_cast<Derived*>(this));
    }

private:

    // This is the problematic function
    template<IsEventType Dispatchable, CanDispatch<Dispatchable> Dispatcher>
    void dispatchEvent(const Dispatchable& e, Dispatcher* dispatcher)
    {
        dispatcher->dispatch(e);
    }

    void dispatchEvent(...) {}
};


class MyModule : public Module<MyModule>
{
public:
    void dispatch(const EventA& event) {
        std::cout << "Handling EventA in MyModule" << std::endl;
    }

    void dispatch(const EventB& event) {
        std::cout << "Handling EventB in MyModule" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    MyModule m;

    m.onEvent(EventA{});
    m.onEvent(EventB{});
    m.onEvent(EventC{});
}


I have tried writing this instead of templated version, but it never gets called
// Also tried CanDispatch<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(e)>>
void dispatchEvent(const IsEventType auto& e, CanDispatch<decltype(e)> auto* dispatcher)
{
    dispatcher->dispatch(e);
}


P.S.1. Also, if someone can recommend me a cleaner and more concise approach, I would be happy.
P.S.2. Is there a way to avoid having to declare derived functions before base function in this case?


derived->dispatch(e); - what is derived? Did you mean dispatcher->dispatch(e);? Both versions work if you do that substitution. Voting to close as a typo.

@TedLyngmo That was a typo while simplifying an example of a problem. Second version still does not work.

The second version works fine, demo. What compiler (and version of it) are you using?

Demo works as intended. Copied your code and it still does not work with Visual Studio 2022 (v143). Seems like a MSVC problem?

Yeah, I verified it in MSVC. Hmm... perhaps you should write a bug report.

@TedLyngmo Seems to be already fixed in latest version.

You may be able to get advice on "cleaner and more concise approach" by presenting your working code (with its unit tests if you can) over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users first, as some things are done differently over there - in particular, we want to see complete, real code rather than the minimal example that SO requires.

This seems to be another msvc bug which is fixed in latest trunk version.

Indeed! I upgraded my local installation of VS2022 to version "17.11.0 Preview 6.0" and it fixed the issue!
